# Fixed div while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

At a point of my page , I have a div 100% width containing 2 divs in float , 50% width each , one of them has a bigger height then the main div , but the overflow is set scroll. So what I need is that when I scroll my page , and I arrive at the div containing the 2 divs , the page scroll stops , and scrolls only the div with overflow set scrolling , and after I finish scrolling that div , my page can start scrolling again..

Comment: Hmm, sounds abit like you want to change the focus from the page to your div when you reach it. What have you tried so far and where does it give an error? And why would you want this kind of behavior to begin with. :x

Comment: yes that's right , I try to get it blocked when I reach it , and after I finish scrolling it , continue to scroll , my page.. Till now I tryed javascript but I couldn't do what I want..

Comment: You could probably do some nasty things with an onscroll event listener and calculating where the div starts, then change the focus to the div. (dont forget to put a tab-index on it if you want to focus it.) But all in all I would advice against this type of design. Can't you just change the layout?

Comment: Yes I could but I definitely want to find out how to do this..

Answer (score 0):

Just a snippet to show how it 'could' be done. Myself I wouldn't use this, since listening for each scroll event can be very costly in performance.

```
var div = document.querySelector('yourDivReference'),
    focussed = false;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function ( event ) {
    if (!focussed && window.pageYOffset >= (div.offsetTop - 2)) {
        div.focus();
        focussed = true;
    }
});
```

Tested on IE. In other browsers you might have to use different properties than offsetTop and pageYOffset. The idea is that you calculate how much the window has scrolled. Once you get to the scrollable div location, you put the focus on the div so that the div will scroll instead. You can add the opposite yourself, where you check the end of the div scrolling, so you can switch focussed back to false, put focus back on the body and then continue scrolling there. Don't forget to put a tab-index on any element you want to focus. You might have to wrap the floating elements into another non-floating container if they don't give accurate positions.